# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

`//`This should trigger an email from a google sheet (data from a google form) when pet vaccinations are due, reminding the pet owner to vaccinate their pet and asking them to check their contact details are correct, with a URL link to go back and edit the data.  when I run this code I get an error Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange.

`your text`    function reminderEmail() {

`your text`  var fullname = 8;
`your text`var petname = 6;
`your text`  var address = 9;
`your text` var cellnumber = 10;
`your text`  var firstcellnumber = 11;
`your text`  var secondcellnumber = 12;
`your text`  var editURL = 15;
`your text`  var email = 2;

`your text`  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Users');

`your text`  var data = sheet.getDataRange("A1:P" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

`your text`  var users = data.slice(1);

`your text`  var today = new Date();

`your text`  data = data.filter(function(r){return r[15] == false });

`your text`  data.forEach(function(row){

`your text`   users.forEach((user, index) => {
`your text`      if (user[14]==''){
`your text`        const date = new Date(user [13]);
`your text`        const diff = Math.round((date-today)/1000*60*60*24);
`your text`        const range = sheet.getRange(index+2,15);
`your text`        if(diff>0){
`your text`          var subject = 'Reminder to Revaccinate and Update records';
`your text`          var message =
`your text`         'Please revaccinate  '+ row[6] +' and check that the following contact details we have, are correct' +
`your text`         '\n' +
`your text`         'Name:' +
`your text`         row[8] +
`your text`         '\n' +
`your text`         'Cell Number:' +
`your text`         row[10] +
`your text`         '\n' +
`your text`         '1st friend/family Cell Number:' +
`your text`         row[11] +
`your text`         '\n' +
`your text`         '2nd friend/family Cell Number:' +
`your text`         row[12] +
`your text`          '\n' +
`your text`         'Address:' +
`your text`         row[9] +
`your text`         '\n' +
`your text`         'Once revaccinated, please click on this link to enter the new revaccination date and UPDATE your contact details if they have changed at all.  If your pet has passed, updating the database will also stop these emails coming through.' +
`your text`        row[15] +
`your text`          '\n' +
`your text`         ' Kind Regards, The Vet Council of Zimbabwe ' ;
`your text`          GmailApp.sendEmail(row[mail], subject, message);

`your text`          range.setValue('sent' +today);
`your text`        }
`your text`        Logger.log(diff);
`your text`      }else{
`your text`     Logger.log(user[14]);
`your text`      }});
`your text`  });
`your text`}

Comment: About your error of `ReferenceError: SpreadSheetApp is not defined reminderEmail @ reminder.gs:12`, in this case, please modify `SpreadSheetApp` to `SpreadsheetApp`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Thanks so much, here's the next one Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = sheet.getDataRange("A1:P" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

The error to your question is that `.getDataRange()` does not accept any parameters/arguments. It must only appear as `.getDataRange()`.

- [.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

---

This Sheet Class method selects the entire dimensions where data is present, meaning it will select the largest range of data.

If your sheet contains data past `A1:P`, you are better off using `.getRange()`, or using `.getDataRange()` in combination with `.offset()`.

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

---

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)